# Extracting Individual trajectories in Lavaan Growth Curve Models

Tags: r, factor-analysis, r-lavaan

I have successfully modeled longitudinal data from a study using the growth() function in the Lavaan package for R. I cannot find it documented anywhere on how to extract the predicted trajectories for each participant. I can only find the predicted trajectory for the group as a whole (given under the "Intercepts" portion of the summary output).

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example of the model you are fitting please: Id guess the lavaan function help files will have one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lavPredict

```
model.syntax <- '
# intercept and slope with fixed coefficients
i =~ 1*t1 + 1*t2 + 1*t3 + 1*t4
s =~ 0*t1 + 1*t2 + 2*t3 + 3*t4

# regressions
i ~ x1 + x2
s ~ x1 + x2

# time-varying covariates
t1 ~ c1
t2 ~ c2
t3 ~ c3
t4 ~ c4
'

fit <- growth(model.syntax, data=Demo.growth)
summary(fit)

head(lavPredict(fit))
```

Which will produce predicted estimates for each individual

```
              i            s
[1,]  1.1378809  0.676301228
[2,] -2.5421940 -1.425974525
[3,] -0.1279434  0.966734762
[4,]  1.1682777  1.477200679
[5,] -0.5141435  0.006995809
[6,] -1.2646865  0.524024630
```

Comment: Thank you, I believe this is what I am looking for. However I tried this with many of models and all of them give a similar error.

"Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, , ov.x.dummy.lv.idx, value = c(2.14028787487844,  : 
  subscript out of bounds"

I should perhaps mention two things that could be related to this error. One, Lavaan gives me a warning message in my models about some cases being empty and therefore removed, and two, rather than having a simple intercept and slope term, some of my models have higher order terms representing quadratic and or cubic change over time.

Comment: I have not used lavPredict in production, however, playing around with it I know that it did not like missing data. I think for this sort of thing you best bet would be asking the question on the lavaan google groups page.